# Mockito - Mock a statement to test the inline implementation

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

I am trying to mock a statement which has an inline implementation. I want to test the implementation:

```
commonUtils.getCommandStack().execute(new RecordingCommand(commonUtils.getTed()) {
      @Override
      protected void doExecute() {
        //Statements needs to be tested
      }
    });
```

I mocked `commonUtils.getCommandStack()` and `commonUtils.getTed()`.
I tried two approaches but none of them letting the control to inside the `doExecute()` method.

I tried 2 approaches but none of them working for me.

**Approach 1**:
Mocking the inline implementation like below but did not work

```
`TransactionalEditingDomain mockTed = Mockito.mock(TransactionalEditingDomain.class);
    Mockito.when(mockCommonUtils.getTed()).thenReturn(mockTed);
    CommandStack mockCommandStack = Mockito.mock(CommandStack.class);
    Mockito.when(mockTed.getCommandStack()).thenReturn(mockCommandStack);
    Mockito.doNothing().when(mockCommandStack).execute(new RecordingCommand(mockTed) {
      @Override
      protected void doExecute() {
      }
    });`
```

**Approach 2**
Mocking the `RecordingCommand` like below but did not work

```
`TransactionalEditingDomain mockTed = Mockito.mock(TransactionalEditingDomain.class);
    Mockito.when(mockCommonUtils.getTed()).thenReturn(mockTed);
    CommandStack mockCommandStack = Mockito.mock(CommandStack.class);
    Mockito.when(mockTed.getCommandStack()).thenReturn(mockCommandStack);
    Command recordingCommandMock = Mockito.mock(Command.class);
    Mockito.doNothing().when(mockCommandStack).execute(recordingCommandMock);`
```

Please help me what should I do to get the control inside `doExecute()` method because I have many methods like this in util.

Comment: In both the approaches all the mocks are fine and my test cases is passing but it is skipping the doExecute() method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write your own code to `answer` the mocked call.  In this case, you can retrieve the object that is passed in and call it from there.

```
Mockito.when(mockCommandStack.execute()).thenAnswer(invocation -> {
    RecordingCommand commandReceived = (RecordingCommand)invocation.getArguments[0];
    commandReceived.doExecute(); // or whatever method applies here
});
```

Comment: Mockito.when is not applicable on void type, mockCommandStack.execute() returns void.

Answer (score 0):

Unittest verify *public observable* behavior (return values and/or communication with dependencies)  of the unit under test.

Your *inline implementation* is an **implementation detail** which unittest expicitly do not test.

You should refactor you production code so the the *inline implementation* becomes a testable unit of its own.